# Connecting between iPhone and server

Tags: iphone, json

I am iPhone developer. I have used JSON framework to communicate between iphone and server, send and receive response. But besides JSON, I would like to know more framework that allow us to communicate between iphone and server. Do you suggest some framework?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST, XML, HTML and parsing… the possibilities are endless. The best protocols to use so that you can use open-sourced and well tested code are JSON and XML

Comment: I would like to send image data from iPhone to server and vice versa. Would you please show me how can I do that with JSON?

Comment: You can send files with ASIHTTPRequest easily — while with JSON it will be quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) makes the communictaion to HTTP-Server really easy. You can send/retrieve JSON, XML, HTML, Files,...

[cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) allows you to start your own Web server on the device. Again JSON, XML, HTML, Files,...

**edit** [sending files to server](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```